# Cannot use the count() function in a query containing subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, view

I have the below query working fine.

```
SELECT
   (SELECT MAX(LOG_DATE) FROM LOGTABLE WHERE ID=A.ID AND STATUS = 'NEW') AS DATE1,
   (SELECT MAX(LOG_DATE) FROM LOGTABLE WHERE ID=A.ID AND STATUS= 'OLD') AS DATE
FROM TABLE1 A
WHERE 
   A.STATUS ('NEW') OR 
   A.ID IN (
      SELECT DISTINCT ID 
      FROM LOGTABLE 
      WHERE LOG_DATE BETWEEN @DATETIME AND @DATETIME AND STATUS = 'OLD'
  )
```

Now I wanted to count the `MAX(LOG_DATE)`.

Below is what I have tried.

```
SELECT
   COUNT((SELECT MAX(LOG_DATE) FROM LOGTABLE WHERE ID=A.ID AND STATUS = 'NEW')) AS DATE1,
   COUNT((SELECT MAX(LOG_DATE) FROM LOGTABLE WHERE ID=A.ID AND STATUS= 'OLD')) AS DATE
FROM TABLE1 A

WHERE 
   A.STATUS ('NEW') OR 
   A.ID IN (
      SELECT DISTINCT ID 
      FROM LOGTABLE 
      WHERE LOG_DATE BETWEEN @DATETIME AND @DATETIME AND STATUS = 'OLD'
   )
```

It resulted in a below error:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an
> aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: `COUNT` around that subquery doesn't make sense; the `COUNT` of a subquery that returns a `MAX` is going to be either `1` or `0` (depending on if any non-`NULL` rows are found). What are you *actually* trying to achieve by `COUNT`ing those subqueries?

Comment: Some sample data and expected result would help a lot here to make things clear

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think filtering the Raw data and after that applying, the count would be good option,

```
;WITH CTE AS (SELECT
   (SELECT MAX(LOG_DATE) FROM LOGTABLE WHERE ID=A.ID AND STATUS = 'NEW') AS DATE1,
   (SELECT MAX(LOG_DATE) FROM LOGTABLE WHERE ID=A.ID AND STATUS= 'OLD') AS DATE
FROM TABLE1 A
WHERE 
   A.STATUS ('NEW') OR 
   A.ID IN (
      SELECT DISTINCT ID 
      FROM LOGTABLE 
      WHERE LOG_DATE BETWEEN @DATETIME AND @DATETIME AND STATUS = 'OLD'
  ))

SELECT COUNT(DATE1),COUNT(Date)   FROM CTE
```

Comment: This what I was exactly looking for also could you please tell me how to sum those date1 count and date count. I'm getting the same error as I mentioned this post

Comment: You can use another CTE or Derived Table to make it simple.